# Contradiction - ML lemma

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, inequality

I seemed to get a contradiction from applying the ML lemma to $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+1} dz$ where $\gamma: z = t$ and $t$ goes from $0$ to $a$ ($a$ is a fixed real number). The length of $\gamma$ is clearly $a$, and on $\gamma$

$$\left| \frac{1}{z^2+1} \right| \leq \frac{1}{|z|^2 -1} \leq \frac{1}{a^2-1} $$

Thus

$$\left| \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+1} dz \right| \leq \frac{a}{a^2-1}$$

If we take $a \to \infty$ on both sides, then this is saying

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx =0$$

which we know is untrue (it should be $\pi/2$). Can someone point to me where I made a mistake? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lvert z\rvert\leqslant a$, $\dfrac1{\lvert z\rvert^2-1}\geqslant\dfrac1{a^2-1}$.

Comment: I knew it must have been a silly mistake! Thank you so much for pointing this out!!